# extract-text-webpack-plugin output css file, image path wrong?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I use extract-text-webpack-plugin output css file into a folder, the image url is wrong, my webpack config is below:

```
"use strict";
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// webpack plugins
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/scripts/main.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        //publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: 'js/[name]-[hash].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,   
                loader: 'babel',    
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
        },{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass!postcss')
        },{
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!postcss')
        },{
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|svg|eot|ttf)/,
                loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=10000'
        },{
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
                loaders: [
                    'file?name=images/[name].[ext]',
                    //'image-webpack'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    // image handle
    // imageWebpackLoader: {
    // progressive: true,
    // optimizationLevel: 3,
    // interlaced: false,
    // pngquant: {quality: "65-70", speed: 4}
    // },

    postcss: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],

    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('This file is created by yugasun'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'RedChild',
            template: __dirname + '/app/template/index.tmpl.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name]-[hash].css')
    ]
};
```

my output 'build' folder tree like this:

```
.
├── css
│   └── main-72c33a6c0ad73a5a0403.css
├── images
│   ├── arrow.png
|   |.....
│   └── wrong_title.png
├── index.html
└── js
    └── main-72c33a6c0ad73a5a0403.js
```

But in my output css file the image url is 'images/arrow.png', what I want is like '../images/arrow.png'.

Then I add the extract-text-webpack-plugin options like below:

Change:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name]-[hash].css')
```

To:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name]-[hash].css', {
            publicPath: '../'
        })
```

But the parameter 'publicPath' doesn't work,  in my output css file the image url is still 'images/arrow.png'.

My package.json is like bellow:

```
{
  "name": "h5-webpack-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "H5 Develop template.",
  "main": "bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --content-base build --port 8014 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.production.js --progress"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/yugasun/H5%2Bwebpack.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "ES6",
    "HTML5"
  ],
  "author": "yugasun",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.10",
    "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.8",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "normalize.css": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.2",
    "webpack-spritesmith": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/yugasun/H5%2Bwebpack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/yugasun/H5%2Bwebpack#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "weui": "^0.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncomment your publicPath and you will be surprised with the results

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Try setting `output.publicPath` to `/`

Comment: So how did you solved it? I met exactly the same problem

Comment: In my case it was combination of output.publicPath and params of url-loader

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [output.publicPath](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) which actually specifies the public url of your output files? This works for me well.